# MySQL Duplicate Row and Update both old and new rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I need to duplicate a row in SQL, update one column in the old row and update one column in the new row.

Using MariaDB/MySQL

| id | attribute | value | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | attribute_x | 0 | 0 | null |
| 2 | attribute_y | 1 | 0 | null |

I want to:

1. Get all rows where attribute = attribute_x
2. Set the end_date of that row to the current timestamp.
3. Duplicate that row.
4. On the new row, set the start_date to the current timestamp.
5. On the new row, set the end_date to null.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Was one of those "not sure where to start" things. My initial approach was to get a list of row ids and do the update query on end_date on those ids. Easy, but then didn't know how to duplicate those rows easily, and if I did how to get the ids of the new rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is two operations:

```
update t
    set end_date = now()
    where attribute = 'attribute_x';

insert into t (attribute, value, start_date, end_date)
    select attribute, value, now(), null
    from t
    where attribute = 'attribute_x';
```

Comment: Thanks, was just a little confused about the insert statement there, namely
   `select attribute, value, now(), null` but think I get it now.